# How to compile a .java file which is been arbitrarily named different from public class name

Tags: java, compilation

I had been creating an online judge platform like codeforces.com on Django recently. Now, I'm struck across a problem that the user may possibly upload a Java file for testing with the filename different from the public class defined inside it. Yet, I should compile it automatically. So, what could be a possible solution to this?

If it's impossible to compile the file without renaming it properly, I need guidance how this 'renaming' can be done using a script/code?

Comment: Fail them.
The submitter has not submitted valid Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiert would be probably to parse the uploaded Java file using something like [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser), then extract the package name and top-level class name and rename the uploaded file accordingly.

By the way, make sure you run the uploaded code in a pretty sandboxed environment.

Comment: Yes, now it seems like thats the simplest way to do! Thank you

Comment: And about the 'sandboxing' thing, I was thinking about some simpler options I have. Being a 'newbie', I found all the answers on google a bit complicated. What is the way you suggest for sandboxing?

Comment: @user104014 I'm not competent in sanboxing, you better ask this separately. I'd just run the whole thing in Docker but I'm not sure if Docker is "unescapable".

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It will be a compilation error. file name should be same as public class name.
hence not possible at all

Comment: Well in that case, how can I write a code to rename the file properly so that it compiles?

Comment: you can create a new file with same code as uploaded file , use java file io for this and give name as public class. you need to parse uploaded file and read line by line and get public class name and create file with that name with content of uploaded file

Comment: Thanks! That was the way I was heading to. But felt that I possibly complicating things due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: Do edit the answer accordingly! I shall accept it if no other solution pops up :) Thanks again!